# Winforms chart is empty

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I made a simple project with default winforms chart with no changes and button.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Dictionary<int, double> L { get; set; }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        L = new Dictionary<int, double>();
        chart1.DataSource = L;
        chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Key";
        chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Value";

    }

    private void Generate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        L.Clear();
        Random R = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberNUD.Value; i++)
        {
            L.Add(i, R.NextDouble() * 100);
        }
    }
}
```

But after click Chart is still empty. Datasource have some values, but `chart1.Series[0].Points.Count == 0`
Did I miss something?

Comment: What is `Generate` being called by? Did you set that up as the button's event handler?

Comment: And what is `numberNUD`?

Comment: Yes, it is. And it was handled properly.
numberNUD - is an Numeric Up Down contol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you call the Generate method somewhere? You should first call it so it can fill the Dictionary with some random values.

Comment: Sure I did. It is a button event handler. Afterall L has some values, chart1.DataSource has same values, chart1.Series[0].Points.Count == 0.

Comment: I think you should also call the chart1.DataBind() method, it binds the data from the data source to the control

Comment: Thanks, that is a solution.

Comment: @MateoVelenik I would edit your post to include your comment.  Otherwise, it doesn't look much like an answer and could be flagged for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you set your DataSource once, does not mean that it will update itself when your model updates.

You need to set the data again after you change the model.

```
L.Clear();
Random R = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < numberNUD.Value; i++)
{
    L.Add(i, R.NextDouble() * 100);
}
chart1.DataSource = L; //this!
chart1.DataBind(); //and this if it doesn't work
```

Comment: No, DataSource updates well after L is being updated.

Comment: I just see it while debugging.